# How to call files from a page in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm running a nodeJS server with the following structure:

```
├── init.js
├── Integration
│   └── [libraries and stuff]
├── package.json
└── views
    ├── 3Dmodel.html
    ├── 404.html
    ├── index.html
    └── models
        └── damaliscus_korrigum.ply
```

In `init.js` (file launched to launch the server) I have:

```
createServer: function(){
        var express = require("express");
        var app = express();
        var http = require('http');
        var server = http.createServer(app);
        var router = express.Router();
        var path = __dirname + '/views/';

        app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/images/logo.png'));

        router.use(function (req,res,next) {
        console.log("/" + req.method);
        next();
        });

        router.get("/",function(req,res){
        res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
        });

        router.get("/3Dmodel",function(req,res){
        res.sendFile(path + "3Dmodel.html");
        }); //same for all pages
}
```

I want to call the file `/views/models/damaliscus_korrigum.ply` in `/views/3Dmodel.html` here:

```
var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();

loader.load( 'damaliscus_korrigum.ply', function ( geometry ) { ... }
```

but what path should I use to call it? `/models/damaliscus_korrigum.ply` hasn't worked, nor has `models/damaliscus_korrigum.ply` or `./models/damaliscus_korrigum.ply`.

Comment: What do you mean by "call"? And what is supposed to call the file? Do you mean the browser via a HTTP request?

Comment: I'll clarify in the OP, but I mean I have a function in 3Dmodel.html that requires this file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to serve the models from your server (so that the client can request it), for serving a static directory [`Express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) is a good choice:

```
 app.use("/models/", express.static(path + "/models/"));
```

Now your client can send requests that get answered.